# Pagination not showing 1 of last page

Tags: pagination, rdlc

I am using `RDLC Report` in my project .

One of the issues i am facing is regarding paging.If I have 10 pages in the report , paging should be shown as `1 of 10`,but instead its showing as `1 of 2`,On clicking the `Next button` it is showing as `2 of 3`.So we cannot know how many page exists in the report unless we click the `last page button`.

Any Idea of how to implement the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression in header/footer section:

```
="pag. " & Globals!PageNumber & "/" & Globals!TotalPages
```